# add trailing slash after removing .html extention

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, html5

My website is **non www** ,it has **wordpress in subdirectory** and some static webpages in the **root** and **other subdirectory**

1. i want to remove .html extention from the webpages in the root and
   the others static webpages in subdirectory.
2. add slash at the end.
3. 301 redirect from non slash to url with slash.

**so it should be**

/articles.html **to** /articles/

**and**

/subdirectory/book.html **to** /subdirectory/book/

the below code

1. **working with non slash at the end**
2. **redirect 301 url with slash to non**

here's my .htaccess

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>     
 Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews


RewriteEngine On     
RewriteBase /

#removing trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

#www to non
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

#index redirect 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/     
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://domain.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html     
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L] 
</IfModule>
```

PS everything is ok with the wordpress , the problems with static pages only.

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

I seem not to be able to comment, it seems, but i am guessing wordpress has a separate .htaccess file that contains extra rules in order to make those pages work.
I would guess your static pages will need extra explicit rules these can be added to the .htaccess or in the virtualhost but in both cases should look like:

    `RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^staticpage1$ ./staticpage1.html 
    RewriteRule ^staticpage2$ ./staticpage2.html`

Comment: yeah wordpress has a separate .htaccess

Comment: ok then you could try add a rule to explicitly set the redirects like: 'RewriteRule ^page$ ./page.html'

Comment: can you post the full code ?

Comment: something like: '
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^staticpage1$ ./staticpage1.html
RewriteRule ^staticpage2$ ./staticpage2.html
'

Comment: not working , it gives 404

Comment: If you want to implement via the .htaccess (and that .htaccess is in the root) it will require full (relative to webroot) paths of the .html files rather than ./ but should work. in your example you said /subdirectory/book/ and /subdirectory/book.html in which case the redirect rule would look like "RewriteRule ^subdirectory/book$ ./subdirectory/book.html" the apache logs located in /var/log/(httpd|apache2)/ should also help identify what is being requested and give better visibility over the error.